# Best way to search result from array of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cocoa-touch, filter

I'm new to Swift language so playing with **Playground.**

As my title saying what is the best way to search result from the array of the dictionary?

**Ex.**

Below is my Array I created for learning purpose.

```
let array = [
    ["name": "Amit", "age": "27", "rollno": 12],
    ["name": "Ananad", "age": "26", "rollno": 10],
    ["name": "Kashyap", "age": "25", "rollno": 11],
    ["name": "Raj", "age": "25", "rollno": 07],
    ["name": "Akshya", "age": "28", "rollno": 13]
]
```

And I want to search **"name"** based on user input. Look at below stuff what I have done.

```
let strSeach = "k"
let searchResult = myArray.filter{String(($0["name"] as! String).characters.prefix(strSeach.characters.count)).lowercased() == strSeach.lowercased()}

print("index => \(searchResult)")
```

**Output is:**

> searchResult => [["rollno": 11, "name": "Kashyap", "age": "25"]]

But confusion, Is it right way to search? I used `characters.prefix`, `lowercased()` is it good or another best way?

and If I want to apply multiple searches like search by "name", "age" etc. then how can we achieve it in **swift filter?**

I think we can't use `NSPredicate` with Swift `Array`? otherwise, we can do it by following

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS [c] %@ OR age CONTAINS [c]", strSeach)
```

Like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contains` keyword in the filter as follows,

```
let searchResult = myArray.filter{String(($0["name"] as! String).lowercased().contains(strSeach.lowercased())}
```

For Multiple filters (i am adding condition based on your predicate),

```
let searchResult = myArray.filter{(String(($0["name"] as! String).lowercased().contains(strSeach.lowercased())) || (String(($0["age"] as! String).lowercased().contains(strSeach.lowercased()))}
```

Answer (score 1):

**With Filters**

You can use this

```
let array = [
["name": "Amit", "age": "27", "rollno": 12],
["name": "Ananad", "age": "26", "rollno": 10],
["name": "Kashyap", "age": "25", "rollno": 11],
["name": "Raj", "age": "25", "rollno": 07],
["name": "Akshya", "age": "28", "rollno": 13]
]

let searchSting = "am"

var search = array.filter { ($0["name"] as!    String).lowercased().contains(searchSting.lowercased()) }
```

**Output**

```
[["rollno": 12, "name": "Amit", "age": "27"]]
```

**WITH Predicates**

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS [c] %@ OR age == %@", searchSting)
search = array.filter { searchPredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[["rollno": 12, "name": "Amit", "age": "27"]]
```

Comment: Yes, Good idea thanks for improve knowledge but if I want to multiple search like NSPredicate then?

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo You can put && or || as per your conditions i.e `var search = array.filter { ($0["name"] as! String).lowercased().contains(searchSting.lowercased()) && ($0["rollno"] as! Int) > 13 }`

Comment: And Also age should be `Int`  so you don't need to type case every time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSPredicate` if you want, but note that it is slower than `filter`.

You just need to convert your swift array to an `NSArray` then call `filtered`.

Also, here's another way of doing this using swift filter:

```
let searchResult = array.filter { 
    ($0["name"] as! String).lowercased().hasPrefix(strSeach.lowercased()) }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

### You should use a Model Value

First of all you should define the following Model Value to represent your data

```
struct Person {

    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let rollno: Int

    init?(dict:[String:Any]) {
        guard
            let name = dict["name"] as? String,
            let ageText = dict["age"] as? String,
            let age = Int(ageText),
            let rollno = dict["rollno"] as? Int
            else { return nil}

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.rollno = rollno
    }
}
```

Now, given your initial array

```
let data = [
    ["name": "Amit", "age": "27", "rollno": 12],
    ["name": "Ananad", "age": "26", "rollno": 10],
    ["name": "Kashyap", "age": "25", "rollno": 11],
    ["name": "Raj", "age": "25", "rollno": 07],
    ["name": "Akshya", "age": "28", "rollno": 13]
]
```

you can get an array of `Person(s)`

```
let persons = data.flatMap(Person.init)
```

### Persons where name contains a String

Now the filtering part is trivial, look

```
let personsWhereNameContainsK = persons.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains("k") }
```

Result

```
[
    Person(name: "Kashyap", age: 25, rollno: 11),
    Person(name: "Akshya", age: 28, rollno: 13)
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and improve my knowledge.